# UWP ColorPicker transfer color between sheets using Binding

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Im trying to pass the selected colour from my Colorpicker into another

I have got the following ColorChanged event that successfully writes to console it is located on the Settings_Page.xaml part of my project:

```
public Color _TextColour;

        private void TextColourPicker_ColorChanged(ColorPicker sender, ColorChangedEventArgs args)
        {

            _TextColour = TextColourPicker.Color;
            Debug.WriteLine(_TextColour);
        }
```

Im then trying to "read" this into a XAML Binding on a seperate page called MainPage.xaml. It is meant to change the colour of the navigation view items. Im trying to do this with the following:

```
  <NavigationViewItem x:Name="TestItem"                                         
                                        Content="ColourTest" 
                                        Tag="Test_Page" 
                                        FontSize="22" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                                        Foreground="{Binding Path=Settings_Page._TextColour, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Shop"/>
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
```

It currently does not work. It displays the text as Black. I feel like I have approached this from the wrong angle but not sure where im going wrong. I feel like the issue is definitely not in the SettingsPage but in the way im handling the Binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform data binding between two different pages. In UWP there is a `Frame` control which is used for navigation between pages and handles `Page` lifetime. The key observation is that when you navigate between pages, there is always just one page in memory (unless you use `NavigationCacheMode`). So once you navigate back from `SettingsPage`, it is gone and you cannot bind to it. Also - navigating to `SettingsPage` again yields a new instance of the page, which is also good to know - data-binding requires you to bind to an instance and that in this case changes.

So if you want to pass some value between two pages, you will need some other mechanism to achieve that. The simplest approach would be some kind of `static` class where you would assign the selected color or have a `public static` property on the first page that you would assign before navigating from the second page. But remember, that you then also need an additional non-static property for the data-binding as it does not work with `static`. This is surely not the cleanest solution but it gets the job done in simpler scenarios.

If you have a MVVM framework in place, you can solve this in a better way if your navigation stack view models stay in memory - you can, for example, use a Event Hub or Messenger and publish a message with the set data that the receiver page subscribes to. MvvmCross and Mvvm Light both have solutions capable of doing this.

Comment: This explains a lot and i feel stupid that i didnt see this as a reason. Thank you for the advice

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :-) ! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Foreground is Brush type property, and you are binding Color type value. Change the type of _TextColour to Brush, and populate it with

```
_TextColour = new SolidColorBrush(TextColourPicker.Color);
```

Comment: Hi, unfortuantely, ive tried doing this just now and it doesnt work. It outputs the following to the console instead of the #FFFFFF that i was doing: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush. Ive defined a public Brush _TextColour and changed the ColorChanged to the New SolidColorBrush as suggested

Comment: Console will show Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush as it is the ToString() method output run with SolidColorBrush object. If the the binding still does not work then you may have wrong binding path

Comment: current binding path doesnt include .xaml at the end. Should it?

Comment: My main issue was understanding how the binding actually works when dealing with different sheets. I just need to know how to resolve the Binding property and where to direct the path. As far as i was aware Settings_Page._TextColour should have been sufficient. Now its changed to a brush i cannot see why this isnt working :/